# Read Data from 2 different columns and use that data to create another column in the same table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I am trying to see if this is even possible, if so i would need some insight on how to do this.

I have created a statement below

```
select wp_cart66_orders.*, wp_cart66_order_items.* from wp_cart66_orders, wp_cart66_order_items where wp_cart66_orders.id=wp_cart66_order_items.order_id and wp_cart66_orders.status = 'new';
```

the 2 colums that i am looking at are

```
item_number and product_price
```

within the 2 columns the data looks like below
item_number:purp1
product_price: 53.00

each time i see purp1 and 53.00 i want to insert a 13 in that same table in a new column called weight

does that make sense? is this even possible in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add columns to your tables, then your table design is not finished, and you should go back to the table and re-think your tables.

If you need to display a value on a result when two fields have some values, then an `if()` should do it:

```
select 
    ...,
    if(item_number == 'purp1' and product_price==53, 13, 0) as aValue
from ...
```

Altering tables in runtime is a delicate issue, and should be avoided, unless is specifically needed by your program

Comment: ok, thank you. the database was already designed. Should i create a view? would i be able to achieve this with a view?

Comment: @drsixpac of course you can, that's what views are for: to present your data in the most convenient way for you